# difference between file extensions?

Tags: html, jpeg, file-extension

What is the difference between these extensions:

1. *.htm or *.html  //HTML
2. *.jpg or *.jpeg or *.jpe //Picture format
3. *.pl or *.plx      //Perl

Thanks,

Comment: nothing different really. they refer to the same thing in their respective content types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, really, except how your operating system may choose to associate them with applications. HTTP itself doesn't even care about extensions.

Some of them are historical. `.htm` stems from the DOS/Windows 3.1 days, when filenames had to be in the "8.3" format, that is, eight characters for the filename, a dot, and three (and only three) letters for the file extension.

Answer (score 5):

[htm vs html](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/WWW_FAQ/ext.html)

[jpg jpeg etc](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Is+there+any+difference+between+JPG+and+JPEG%3F&btnG=Google+Search)

[pl vs plx](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090115105132AAPZhDL)

Answer (score 1):

See this:

**[List of File Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_formats)**

Answer (score 1):

Certain operating systems such as DOS and early versions of Windows had a 3 character limit for the file extension. More modern incarnations of Windows still generate these kind of short file names (a.k.a [8.3 filename](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)) for files with longer file names in order to maintain compatibility with some legacy software.

There is no difference between files with the extension `.htm` vs `.html` or those with `.jpg` vs `.jpeg`.

As for `.pl` vs `.plx`, refer to  [this link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090115105132AAPZhDL) from VoodooChild's post.

Edit: Note that technically a `.pl` file could be a Prolog source file in which case`.pl` could be considered different from the `.plx` extension of a Perl script.